# Cookieless Domain - IP on another port?

Tags: apache2, ip-address, cookieless

I'm trying to establish a [Cookieless Domain](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/request) on my home virtual web server that has no domains name, only an IP address.

I've been trying to simulate the cookieless domain by opening another port on my router and telling Apache to listen for it. Everything loads correctly, but it doesn't seem to be cookieless (which makes sense because it's the same domain name, just a different port).

Is there any way I could set up a Cookieless Domain on my virtual server with no domain names, and only 1 IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always personally thought that browsers would treat sites operating from different ports at the same domain name or IP address as unrelated, for things like cookies or same-origin policy, but your experience seems to indicate this isn't the case.

So I think the answer to your question is:  No, this is not possible.  I would suggest looking into some kind of dynamic DNS setup.

Comment: I'd like to find a free solution that'd be easy to maintain, but buying a couple of domain names may be my only choice here. I thought that the port thing would work as well, but I wasn't able to get it functioning. I've seen some crazy things, and figured it was worth asking at least. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I found a list of dynamic DNS providers here:  http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/   Also, keep in mind if you register a domain name, you effectively get all subdomains, e.g. register yourname.com and you can set img.yourname.com for your cookie-free site (the first part can be anything you want).  These hostnames can both resolve to the same IP address, and indeed you can set up a wildcard DNS record *.yourname.com to point every site to yourname.com

Comment: Having some computer problems, so I won't be able to investigate these for a few days. I won't forget.